# redraw image during excecution WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a smal application that should set a image to red or green depending on some tests that are made. The test can take a few second, and each one has a custom control with an image connected to it. When I click start I would like for the first test to be done, show the result by changing the image on that one, and then move on. But as it is now, all tests are made (maybe 10 seconds), then ALL the lights are changing at the same time. How can I force the custom control to update the image during the excecution?

```
private void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TestObject tObj in tObjList)
        {
            bool testResult = tObj.makeTest();
            foreach (TestShower ts in m_TSList)
            {
                if (tObj == ts.gettObj())
                {
                    if (testResult == true)
                        ts.setLightOn();
                    else
                        ts.setLightOff();

                    ts.UpdateLayout();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }    

public void setLightOn()
    {
        string strUri2 = String.Format(@"pack://application:,,,/;component/Images/Signal_On.png");
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strUri2));
        iStatus.Source = null;
        iStatus.Source = img;
    }

public void setLightOff()
    {
        string strUri2 = String.Format(@"pack://application:,,,/;component/Images/Signal_Off.png");
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strUri2));
        iStatus.Source = null;
        iStatus.Source = img;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read into Async and await and perform each test at the same time and await the results  (obviously this assumes your tests are not interdependant)

and some form of  implementation of

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
var result = ts.makeTest();
setLight1(result);

})
```

Although without knowing more it would seem as though you could perform this using databinding to a ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged on a List of Test Objects.

but not performing the tests asynchronously is the main cause of your issue

i know external links are not really preferred in SO but here is a tutorial

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyFL3hjHADs

Comment: I will do this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Run the tests in the background and then use Dispatcher to update UI thread:
For WPF & Net 4.5. you can use TPL

```
private void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(()=>{
    foreach (TestObject tObj in tObjList)
    {
        bool testResult = tObj.makeTest();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{
        foreach (TestShower ts in m_TSList)
        {
            if (tObj == ts.gettObj())
            {
                if (testResult == true)
                    ts.setLightOn();
                else
                    ts.setLightOff();

                ts.UpdateLayout();
                break;
            }
        }});
       }
    }
  });
}
```